# JPA - get entity's by week number - Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, calendar, entity

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int id;


    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date startDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date endDate;

    /** getters and setters **/
}
```

So I use the type Temporal.DATE for startDate and endDate. Now I want to select by year and weeknumber. What is the best way to do this? I prefer a JPQL query.

For example

```
@Stateless
public class FooBean {
    @Inject
    @MainDB
    EntityManager em;

public List<Foo> getFoos(int weekNumber, int year) {
    TypedQuery<Foo> foos = em.createQuery("...", Foo.class);
    return foos.getResultList();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, I have got a similar requirement now. Did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 4):

You can create an Date like that:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.clear();
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

Date date = calendar.getTime();//first day of week
```

And then use query like

```
:date BETWEEN f.startDate AND f.endDate
```